# Widgets and Notifications on Android 5 (w/ HTC Sense and Nova Launcher)

Tags: lock-screens, 5.0-lollipop, htc-sense, nova-launcher

On my HTC One (M8) I used HTC Sense UI and Nova Launcher. Until recently I was able to customize my lock screen, like adding widgets, and I could see all notification icons.

Now Android has been updated to Lollipop on the HTC One. Unfortunately I cannot add widgets to the lock screen any more, nor are there any icons shown in the notification bar (i.e. there is no notification bar at all on the lock screen).

Is this a Lollipop "feature", or is there any way for me to get back to the old Android 4 lock screen behaviour?

Comment: Google have taken control of your lockscreen,  you can't add widgets sadly and the 3rd party lock screens are blocked. When it comes to the notification bar, it should be there on Lollipop, it is on all my devices. There may be a setting in security or somewhere for this. I'll have a look around for an M8

Comment: @RossC Thanks for your comment. There is no way at all to add widgets to the lock screen under Lollipop? That would be very sad, it was a super useful feature!

Comment: There is no way to add widgets to the lollipop lockscreen. Google's 'new' notification system is the replacement... It's not actually replacing it in any useful way, obviously, but this is what they have decided. It's a typical Google thing: Lollipop (stock) doesn't even have a reboot option, ONLY Power off. They're big on making things 'minimal' but doing so by removing useful functionality.

Comment: That's sad, I really liked my Yatse lock-screen widget :(

Answer (score 2):

I think it shoud be in your lockscreen settings and there should be an option to disable or enable status bar on lockscreen.
My phone has it I think yours should have too.
Its a privacy keeping feature.

Comment: Thanks, I have found the setting for the notifications. But I would also be really interested in widgets :-(